# Triggering Powershell Program on barcode scan event windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell, qr-code, barcode, barcode-scanner

I am looking for using barcode capture event to executing a program (either powershell or simple vbscript) on Windows 10 machine. How can I achieve that? Do I need to create a barcode program embedded in it - if yes, how will it execute? Do I need to capture the scan event in windows machine and write a logic on scan event to execute program - is that possible?
I am not finding any help on internet. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no mechanism that can be called by simply registering an event handler.

Based on the mode and mechanism of the scanner device you are using, you need to create an application program that handles it.

- Hardware type and mode

  - Keyboard input emulation
  - Serial (or Bluetooth) port connection
  - Camera image recognition
- programming

  - The application handles the device directly
  - Libraries and APIs

    - [OPOS](http://monroecs.com/opos.htm)
    - [POS for.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/bb429024(v=winembedded.4))
    - [Windows.Devices.PorintOfService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.pointofservice?view=winrt-19041)
    - [JavaPOS](https://github.com/JavaPOSWorkingGroup/)
    - Various libraries that recognize barcodes from cameras/images

At a minimum, you need to open the device or register a keystroke event handler.
In addition, it will be necessary to send a command to start/stop scanning of the scanner, to distinguish between human-operated keyboard input and notification from the scanner.

It's not impossible to implement them in PowerShell, but it's likely to be difficult and slow.